# Why the separate notation for norm

Tags: metric-spaces, notation, normed-spaces

One usually denotes the norm as $\|\cdot\| $, $\| v\| := \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}.$ However, in metric spaces, one often writes $d(x,y) \equiv \lvert x-y \rvert$.

Since the norm canonically induces the metric space structure on a vector space, why the separate notation for the norm? Why don't we simply denote $| v| := \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$

Comment: Because a norm is something different then a metric. A norm induces a metric, but a metric does not induce a norm. Moreover, not every norm comes from an inner-product, these are all different concepts.

Comment: Any example of a norm that doesn't come from an inner product?

Comment: @marmistrz All the $p$-norms except p=2 are not induced by an inner product.

Comment: In metric spaces which are not normed linear spaces, although I do see the notation $|x-y|$ used sometimes for the metric $d(x,y)$, it usually bothers me because the minus sign makes no sense; it's just some kind of formal replacement for a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional analysis has a lot to do with spaces of functions, as its name suggests (more so historically, but it still does). Using single bars for the norm of a function is ambiguous because  $|f|$ also means the function $|f|(t) = |f(t)|$. Double bars $\|f\|$ eliminate the ambiguity.

By the way, in some function spaces it is important to observe that $\||f|\| \le \|f\|$.

The metric space notation $d(f,g)$ is unambiguous, but more verbose: writing $d(f,0)$ instead of $\|f\|$ gets tedious, and the repetition of "$d$" obscures the symbols that matter the most. Indeed, in some papers and books that have a lot of computation with distances in the same abstract metric space, the authors adopt a different notation such as $|pq|$ or $|p-q|$ for $d(p,q)$. In this case there is no ambiguity because there is no competing absolute value concept.